# How to return object based on value in nested array? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to return all objects that have a specific 'id' in the nested array. In the sample data, I'd like to return all person objects with hobbies id of 2 (hiking).

The other question addresses the problem of finding all values in an array based on an object value.

This question differs from the previous because I need to return all objects based on a value inside of a nested array.

```
[  
   {  
      "id":111222,
      "name":"Faye",
      "age":27,
      "hobbies":[  
         {  
            "id":2,
            "name":"hiking"
         },
         {  
            "id":3,
            "name":"eating"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":223456789001,
      "name":"Bobby",
      "age":35,
      "hobbies":[  
         {  
            "id":2,
            "name":"hiking"
         },
         {  
            "id":4,
            "name":"online gaming"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access specific value from a nested array within an object array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166623/how-to-access-specific-value-from-a-nested-array-within-an-object-array)

Comment: Haven't you already asked the same question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166623/how-to-access-specific-value-from-a-nested-array-within-an-object-array

Comment: Dear Jasmin, SO is not get code for free site. You have to share your efforts as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function hasHobby(person, hobbyId) {
  return person.hobbies.some(function(hobby) {
    return hobby.id === hobbyId;
  });
}

function filterByHobby(people, hobbyId) {
  return people.filter(function(person) {
    return hasHobby(person, hobbyId);
  });
}
```

If you wanna use the new cool ES6 syntax:

```
function filterByHobby(people, hobbyId) {
  return people.filter(
    person => person.hobbies.some(
      hobby => hobby.id === hobbyId
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [  
   {  
      "id":111222,
      "name":"Faye",
      "age":27,
      "hobbies":[  
         {  
            "id":2,
            "name":"hiking"
         },
         {  
            "id":3,
            "name":"eating"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":223456789001,
      "name":"Bobby",
      "age":35,
      "hobbies":[  
         {  
            "id":2,
            "name":"hiking"
         },
         {  
            "id":4,
            "name":"online gaming"
         }
      ]
   }
];

arr.filter(function(obj) {
 var hobbies = obj.hobbies;
 var x = hobbies.filter(function(hob) {
     if (hob.id == "2") return true;
});

if (x.length > 0) return true;
});
```

Comment: You can use `return hobbies.some` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, I think its solve your proble:**

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": 111222,
  "name": "Faye",
  "age": 27,
  "hobbies": [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "hiking"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "eating"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 223456789001,
  "name": "Bobby",
  "age": 35,
  "hobbies": [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "hiking"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "online gaming"
  }]
}];
var x = arr.filter(function(el) {
  var rnel = el.hobbies.filter(function(nel) {
    return nel.id == 2;
  });
  return rnel.length > 0 ? true :false;
});
alert(x.length);
```

Comment: Nice running example