# Retrieving a specific object from JSON

Tags: json, node.js

This is a snippet of a JSON file that was returned by TMDB and I'm trying to access the title of every object. I've tried using the following methods like from this post [How to access specific value from a nested array within an object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166623/how-to-access-specific-value-from-a-nested-array-within-an-object-array?answertab=active#tab-top).

```
"results": [
    {
      "vote_count": 2358,
      "id": 283366,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.5,
      "title": "Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children",
      "popularity": 20.662756,
      "poster_path": "/AvekzUdI8HZnImdQulmTTmAZXrC.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children",
      "genre_ids": [
        18,
        14,
        12
      ],
      "backdrop_path": "/9BVHn78oQcFCRd4M3u3NT7OrhTk.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "A teenager finds himself transported to an island where he must help protect a group of orphans with special powers from creatures intent on destroying them.",
      "release_date": "2016-09-28"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 3073,
      "id": 381288,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.8,
      "title": "Split",
      "popularity": 17.488396,
      "poster_path": "/rXMWOZiCt6eMX22jWuTOSdQ98bY.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Split",
      "genre_ids": [
        27,
        53
      ],
      "backdrop_path": "/4G6FNNLSIVrwSRZyFs91hQ3lZtD.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Though Kevin has evidenced 23 personalities to his trusted psychiatrist, Dr. Fletcher, there remains one still submerged who is set to materialize and dominate all the others. Compelled to abduct three teenage girls led by the willful, observant Casey, Kevin reaches a war for survival among all of those contained within him — as well as everyone around him — as the walls between his compartments shatter apart.",
      "release_date": "2016-11-15"
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i =0; i < obj.results.length; i++) {
 console.log(obj.results[i].title);
}
```

First, we get the results key, and then, iterate over it since it is an array.

Comment: Thanks man! You're a lifesaver since I'm just new to node.js and it can be pretty intimidating when you see a large JSON file like that. Haha

Comment: starting is always difficult, but the journey is worth it!

Answer (score 1):

```
var titles = results.map(function extract(item){return item.title})
```

The map function iterates through the array and builds the resulting array by applying the `extract` function on each item.

Answer (score 0):

Results is nothing more than an array of objects, there's nothing nested. 
You could use [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
results.forEach(function(item){
  console.log(item.title);
});
```